# General question for UV Editing

Tags: uv, shaders

I followed a YT tutorial with an orange, but I used a different stock photo. Unfortunately, my one has more black on the side and my piece looks wrong.
So, my question is, how can I hide the red circled corner?
[image]

Comment: Hello, do you have black areas on your picture? Please pack your image and share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Hello @moonboots File is added https://pasteall.org/blend/5ccedfe302a549b6aeef270b852420d0

Answer (score 6):

Use a **Knife** tool to cut black part ... ?
I deleted half of the mesh and used *Mirror* modifier (so you have less to care).

[image]

Extrude edge and move to centre ...

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

As you see here the UV island is over a part of your image that is transparent (*Alpha 0*), it will appear black unless you plug the *Alpha* output into an *Alpha* input or into the factor of a *Mix Shader*, but you don't want transparency on this part.

[image]

You have several solutions:

- You can move the UV vertices so that they don't overlap transparent areas. To select all these faces in the 3D view, select one and press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> > *Select Similar Normal* and increase the Threshold in the *Operator* box. Now activate the *Proportional Editing* in the *UV Editor* and move the vertices:

[image]

- Or you can switch to *Texture Paint* mode in the 3D view and use the *Clone* brush:

[image]

[image]